# Interrupting/breaking running code, and restart it inside VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've to run some code, which loops through some data. The data is comming from an external source through an add-in, from which I use a user created formula. I suspect, that the add-in uses VBA to extract the data into the sheet.

My problem is, that when I run my code, the formula has not extracted any data into the sheet, so the code provide me with errors.

Is there any way I can interrupt/break/stop my code completely, such that the add-in can work its magic, and then restart my code again?

Thanks for any advice.

I've tried the application.Wait.

The add-in only works when I don't "use" the VB editor. So it seems I've to break up my code, by letting the first part run, open the workbook with the add-in formulas and let it calculate, and then run the second part?
I wonder if it, could be done automatically?

```
Sub BannedWeaponsCheck()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    Dim strISINBanned() As String, strSearch As String, strTmpData(4) As String, _
    strBanned() As String
    Dim varData() As Variant, varBannedData() As Variant, varPapers() As Variant
    Dim lngLast As Long


    Call SpeedOptimizer

    Sheets("Banned weapons").Activate
    i = 1
    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        ReDim Preserve strISINBanned(i)

        strISINBanned(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Sheets("Characteristics").Activate
    lngLast = Cells(12, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    varData = Range(Cells(12, 2), Cells(lngLast, 8)).Value
    j = 1
    For i = LBound(varData) To UBound(varData)
        strSearch = varData(i, 5)
        If IsInArray(strISINBanned, strSearch) = True Then
            'Så er ISIN blandt banned weapons
            Cells(11 + i, 15).Value = "Y"
            strTmpData(1) = Cells(11 + i, 2).Value  'Ticker
            strTmpData(2) = Cells(11 + i, 5).Value  'Long name
            strTmpData(3) = Cells(11 + i, 6).Value  'ISIN
            strTmpData(4) = Cells(11 + i, 7).Value  'CUSIP

            ReDim Preserve varBannedData(j)
            varBannedData(j) = strTmpData
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next


    FindFundForBanned varBanned:=varBannedData, strBanned:=strBanned, varPapers:=varPapers

    'Print
        'Clean existing

        Sheets("Fonde").Activate
        Cells(2, 1).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).ClearContents

    For i = LBound(strBanned) To UBound(strBanned)
        Cells(1 + i, 1) = strBanned(i)
        Cells(1 + i, 2) = varPapers(i)(1)
        Cells(1 + i, 3) = varPapers(i)(2)
    Next

    'The interruption/Break has to come here 

    Call EUSanctionCheck
    Call RestoreSpeedOptimizer
End Sub

Public Sub SpeedOptimizer()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
Public Sub RestoreSpeedOptimizer()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hard to help without seeing some code

Comment: @Rastalamm I've added some code, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Try running your Code without `SpeedOptimizer()`

Comment: @horst Yes, I've just run it without the `SpeedOptimizer()`, still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](https://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut08.htm) that states that the problem you're having is because that Add-ins are primarily intended to add extra functionality to your workbooks and can't be 'seen' by the Visual Basic Editor.

Try to first give your add in a VBA Project Name:

> The first thing to do is give your Add-In a unique VBA Project Name. This is because you are going to refer to it by this name in the next step and if there are more than one with the same name the Visual Basic Editor won't know which one to use.

Then set a reference to the Add-in in your code:

> Open a code module in the workbook in which you want to use the Add-In's functions then go to Tools > References to open the References dialog where you will see a list of all the libraries and other objects (like Add-Ins) to which you can set a reference.

...

> Select your Add-In and click Open. This adds your Add-In to the list where you can select it and click OK.

...

> Now you will be able to use the Add-In's functions in any module in the workbook in which you set the reference and they will be recognized by the Visual Basic Editor...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, that does not do the job. I don't use the add-in formulas in my VBA code. I use the formula in the sheet, and they need to calculate before I run the line: "Call EUSanctionCheck."